# Java Desktop Application Error With Code ORA-12505

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I installed an old application of my office.
When I ran it, it showed error, I checked log and it show like this.

```
Aug 02, 2023 9:59:53 AM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: =============================================
Aug 02, 2023 9:59:53 AM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: #   Starting Application CUAN_CUAN   #
Aug 02, 2023 9:59:53 AM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: =============================================
Aug 02, 2023 9:59:59 AM com.kitacuan.util.DBConnection <init>
SEVERE: Connection DB Failed
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:662)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:560)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:311)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:235)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:178)
    at com.gamatechno.util.DBConnection.<init>(DBConnection.java:79)
    at form.DBQuery.<init>(DBQuery.java:54)
    at form.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:105)
    at form.MainForm$27.run(MainForm.java:1059)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 24 more

Aug 02, 2023 9:59:59 AM form.DBQuery <init>
SEVERE: null
```

Is there any solution for this error? Thank you.

I haven't try anything since I don't understand about oracle database.

Comment: The most likely explanation for that error is that the target database instance is down (or simply doesn't exist anymore), or that the application's database connect string is incorrect. You will need to work with your DBA to determine which.